# Flow type checking for overriden static function extended type argument

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have some basic type that is processing with some class static function. Also I have an extended type, so I want to write an extended class to process it the same way with code reuse.

The code works find, but I can't figure out how to make flow happy here.

Here is a small [example](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AEQIYr6gC8oA3oqKAJYAmAXKAHYCuAtgEZYBOoiAX2TpsoAKIAPFFmZ0sdAkVJ5CxAGQUqLfOyxMAzih41mAc35DEAY2j59+0AGVYugMK37mgJCHCNK6D6LlgoABYmpgAUQbpMivgAlExhNA6UXl48Iaw8zCxY8KAp+pEJANygIKBZKDnMDs5uHvqIXkKWNnYNwQDyYbzuXaBYUjJ03U1DlNTUVTAITK74zMywKMOjsqAABo1Yg-bboADaAIwAuqDwNGE7e32hA81HWrNg3Fb4rPo4GDyw2B46B2zB0WCOqVA7FS+gitDy23iR2OACZLpxWOsRqkUA4TPwZpUwLBOAArLBWdYiHDHADMl3x-VAkBoPEMoHwPFMHBk61gkFAfwBvGB2xiIXCZm2ADpWr4UP5AsEUmZosEmJJpLJ5PEkkVwmlWplsrlKgAqaom+pOXr9HgHBxmsD6ViA6XilVRcXlVrtRBAA):

```
// @flow

type Data = {
  id: number 
}

type ExtendedData = Data & {
  name: string 
}

class SomeClass {
    static something(some: Data): this {
        return new this(); // returns SomeClass
    }
}

class SomeOtherClass extends SomeClass {
    // flow: Cannot extend `SomeClass` [1] with `SomeOtherClass` 
    // because property `name` is missing in `Data` [2] but exists in 
    // object type [3] in the first argument of property `something`.
    static something(some: ExtendedData): this {
        return /* returns SomeOtherClass here */ super.something(some);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point flow complains [is similar to this one](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4585), your implementation breaks **L** in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) i.e. it'll fail in next case:

```
const f = (S: Class<SomeClass>) => {
   S.something({id: 1}) 
}
f(SomeClass); // ok
f(SomeOtherClass); // fail, no name property
```

You can say him that only `Data` is ok as well for `SomeOtherClass`, and [he'll be happy](https://flow.org/try/#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):

```
static something(some: Data | ExtendedData): this {...}
```

Comment: @silent, okay, found something simpler for you